# Pyinstaller created exe file of Pyside2 script

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyside2

I'm having a strange problem. I have created a Python script which uses a custom stock trading algorithm to give buy and sell signals to the user.

I have used PySide2 for the GUI toolkit, but I'm getting the same issue with Tkinter as well.

First, here are the relevant snippets of my code:

1. Main Window

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        ...
        ...

        Create and add GUI widgets
        ...
        ...


        watch_button = QPushButton("Watch")
        watch_button.clicked.connect(self.watch_scrip)

    @Slot()
    def watch_scrip(self, checked):
        ScripWindow(self, ScripInfo(self._scrips_strings[self._scrip_list.currentIndex()])).show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        QApplication.closeAllWindows()
        event.accept()
```

2. Child windows opening for individual scrips being watched

```
class ScripWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent, scrip_info):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        ...
        ...
        Create and add GUI widgets 
        ...
        ...

        self._scrip_queue = Queue()
        self._scrip_algo = ScripAlgo(self._scrip_queue)

        self._scrip_algo_process = Process(target=self._scrip_algo.run_algo) 
        self._scrip_algo_process.start() <-- Start algorithm in a new background process which writes to Queue

        QTimer.singleShot(1000, self._process_queue)

    def _process_queue(self):

        while not self._scrip_queue.empty():
            data_string = self._scrip_queue.get()
            ...
            ...
            Read and display data from the Queue object generated by algorithm 
            ...
            ...

        QTimer.singleShot(1000, self._process_queue)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self._scrip_algo_process.terminate()
        event.accept()
```

The script runs perfectly via Python. Even "pythonw my_app.pyw" runs without console just fine.

The problem arises when I use Pyinstaller to create a .exe file. When I run the .exe file, it opens up the MainWindow. When I press the 'Watch' button, it opens a child window (ScripWindow) like it is supposed to. But it also opens up another Main window.

What could be the problem? And how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer [at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33970690/why-python-executable-opens-new-window-instance-when-function-by-multiprocessing)

It seems that you have to call multiprocessing.freeze_support() at the beginning of your script to enable it to properly run on Windows as an .exe file (if you are using multiprocessing in your script, that is)